# Where should I ask about cloud storage solutions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which site in the Stack Exchange family is the best place for me to ask the following question?

> I'm looking for a cloud synchronisation program that can sync several
>   directories on my local machine with a volume in a cloud.
>
> I want to be able to choose which local directories get synced. So far
>   I've looked at Dropbox and Megacloud but they seem to work by creating
>   a folder on your local machine and whatever you want to sync you have
>   copy to that folder, which is not what I want.
>
> Are there any cloud synchronisation programs that allow me to choose
>   which directories get synced?

Comment: This would qualify as a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) or product recommendation, and as such wouldn't be allowed on any SE site.

Comment: The closest site would normally be Super User, but it explicitly disallows "a shopping or buying recommendation". So as @Servy suggests, there is no such site within the SO/SE family where this would fit. Perhaps a Super User chat might welcome it, but I don't participate in any, so ask first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I suppose what I really want to know is _"does this software feature exist?"_ rather than _"what is the best software to do this feature?"_ So I'll try my luck on Super User, thanks.

Comment: The key is whether you can ask the question __in a constructive way__. See [this Meta SU question](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2088/6442) I asked when I was confused by apparently inconsistent closures.

Comment: @NigelAlderton Even if you re-phrased that, it would still be asking "what are all of the products that do X", which would be a "list of things" question, also not allowed.

Comment: @PopularDemand The question you linked to is interesting. You create the concept of _"shopping/buying .. with a budget of $0."_ which I understand. Even if someone is spending $0, they're still a _"buyer"_ if they accept the recommendation. But my question is _"I want to spend $0. Is there **anything** I can spend my $0 on?"_ not _"what is the best thing to spend my $0 on?"_. That may be a subtle distinction, or not!

Comment: Btw, dropbox works well for this using symbolic links. I am effortlessly synchronizing folders in my work folder on OS X that way

Comment: ... Google "dropbox symlinks" for more info. Eg http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder

Comment: Also, have a look a this meta question on [su] [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372) /cc @PopularDemand

Comment: Related: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions/1003#1003

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this would be on-topic on [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). In the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there, it says that a good software recommendation should have "A **purpose** — a task to accomplish, a user story" and "Some **objective requirements** — a minimum set of features". Here, your purpose or task is to get a cloud storage program and your objective requirement is that the cloud storage program allows you to choose which directories will get synced.